# Display count results of requests with results of jobs horizontally and locations vertically 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

So I have a primary table of data which holds IDs against a job and location, so for example:

**Requests Table dbo.Requests**

```
RequestID    JobID    LocationID
1            3        5
2            4        8
3            3        2
```

**Job Table dbo.Jobs**

```
JobID    JobTitle
1        Job 1
2        Job 2
3        Job 3
```

**Location Table dbo.Locations**

```
LocationID   LocationName
1            Location 1
2            Location 2
3            Location 3
```

Now what I want to do is display a list of counts for jobs done and for locations, something like:

```
Job Title      Total Jobs    Location 1   Location 2  Location 3
Job 1          30            5            15          10
Job 2          10            2            2           6
Job 3          40            22           0           18
```

So I've got the first part fine for displaying the jobs and total count, but I'm stuck getting the locations to list to the right hand side?

```
SELECT 
 job.JobTitle
,isnull(COUNT(req.JobID),0) AS 'Total Jobs'

FROM  Requests req 

RIGHT OUTER JOIN Jobs job
ON req.JobID = job.JobID

GROUP BY job.JobTitle
ORDER BY JobTitle
```

Many thanks

Comment: How many locations are there? Just 3? Or is it unknown?

Comment: Unknown as they will be added to and removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT JobID,JobTitle,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]
FROM
  (
    SELECT j.JobID,j.JobTitle,r.LocationID,r.RequestID
    FROM Jobs j
    LEFT JOIN Requests r ON r.JobID=j.JobID
  ) q PIVOT(COUNT(RequestID) FOR LocationID IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])) p
```

And if you want use dynamic number of columns you can generate script and execute it using EXEC

```
DECLARE @locationIDs varchar(200)=''

SELECT @locationIDs+=CONCAT(',[',LocationID,']')
FROM Locations
ORDER BY LocationID

SET @locationIDs=STUFF(@locationIDs,1,1,'')

--PRINT @locationIDs

DECLARE @query varchar(1000)=CONCAT('SELECT JobID,JobTitle,',@locationIDs,'
FROM
  (
    SELECT j.JobID,j.JobTitle,r.LocationID,r.RequestID
    FROM Jobs j
    LEFT JOIN Requests r ON r.JobID=j.JobID
  ) q PIVOT(COUNT(RequestID) FOR LocationID IN(',@locationIDs,')) p')

--PRINT @query

EXEC(@query)
```

The variant with location titles

```
DECLARE
  @locationIDs varchar(200)='',
  @locationTitles varchar(2000)=''

SELECT
  @locationIDs+=CONCAT(',[',LocationID,']'),
  @locationTitles+=CONCAT(',[',LocationID,'] [',LocationName,']')
FROM Locations
ORDER BY LocationID

SET @locationIDs=STUFF(@locationIDs,1,1,'')
SET @locationTitles=STUFF(@locationTitles,1,1,'')

--PRINT @locationIDs
--PRINT @locationTitles

DECLARE @query varchar(2000)=CONCAT('SELECT JobID,JobTitle,',@locationTitles,'
FROM
  (
    SELECT j.JobID,j.JobTitle,r.LocationID,r.RequestID
    FROM Jobs j
    LEFT JOIN Requests r ON r.JobID=j.JobID
  ) q PIVOT(COUNT(RequestID) FOR LocationID IN(',@locationIDs,')) p')

--PRINT @query

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost there, its listing all the counts against a ward to the right however it is listing the ID as the heading rather than the Locations name?

Comment: @slowlygettingthere - you also can use type varchar(MAX) in DECLARE-blocks if your SQLServer version supports it.

Comment: @slowlygettingthere - I updated my answer one more time.

Comment: I had to use max in the end as it didn't play ball otherwise. Thank you!