# SQL pivot / VLOOKUP query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following simplified table so each stock code has
multiple warehouses and I want to "pivot" it so I can get 
the cost for each warehouse just in 1 line for the stockcode

```
Stockcode | Warehouse | Cost 
A100        WH          100$
A100        ZZ          200$
```

What I would like to have is the following.
So only 1 stockcode line with the warehouse costs pivoted.

```
Stockcode | Cost WH | Cost ZZ
A100        100$      200$
```

I currently did it by exporting it to excell, creating a new sheet and add a new column to the sheet using a VLOOKUP to the main table and add the ZZ cost like that.

How would you turn this around in SQL? I am a bit stuck with understanding how to transform this tabular data in such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do this query using [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select Stockcode, [WH] as CostWH, [ZZ] as CostZZ
from (
  select Stockcode, Warehouse, Cost
  from MyTable
) p
pivot (
  MAX(Cost)
  for Warehouse in ([WH], [ZZ])
) as pvt
order by Stockcode;
```

Test it [on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d3ab/4)

Comment: Thanks a lot gives me exactly what I need, only thing I do not understand is why the usage of Sum() for this?

Comment: @Koen `sum` is invalid for `Cost`

Comment: @YogeshSharma what is the difference between sum and cost for this?

Comment: @Koen i.e. `sum()` function is invalid for `cost` column

Comment: @YogeshSharma Right. I assumed it was an `int` column. Use whatever function makes sense then. For example, `max(Cost)`

Comment: @Koen You have to provide an aggregation function for the case when there are multiple items for the same `Stockcode` and same `Warehouse`.

Answer (score 1):

However, you could also do that by using simple `case` expression if you don't want to go `pivot` or `dynamic pivot`

```
SELECT 
          Stockcode , 
          MAX( CASE (Warehouse) WHEN 'WH' THEN Cost END)[Cost WH],
          MAX(CASE (Warehouse) WHEN 'ZZ' THEN Cost END) [Cost ZZ]
FROM <table> GROUP BY Stockcode
```

Dynamic `pivot` way :

```
DECLARE @Col nvarchar(max), @query nvarchar(max)

select @Col = STUFF(
                    (SELECT  ',' +QUOTENAME(Warehouse) FROM <table> FOR XML PATH('')), 
                    1, 1, ''

                )

SELECT @query = N'select Stockcode, [WH] as CostWH, [ZZ] as CostZZ
             from (
                select Stockcode, Warehouse, Cost
                 from <table>) p
                    pivot (max(Cost) for Warehouse in ('+@Col+')
                    ) as pvt order by Stockcode;'

                    exec(@query)
```

Result :

```
Stockcode  Cost WH  Cost ZZ
A100       100$    200$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `(Stockcode,Warehouse)` is unique in your table.
And I think you can use `PIVOT` like it

```
SELECT Stockcode,[WH],[ZZ]
FROM TestData PIVOT(MAX(Cost) FOR Warehouse IN([WH],[ZZ])) p
```

And use dynamic query for generate query for all the warehouses

```
DECLARE @Warehouses varchar(500)=''

SELECT @Warehouses+=CONCAT(',[',Warehouse,']')
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT Warehouse
    FROM TestData
  ) q
ORDER BY Warehouse

SET @Warehouses=STUFF(@Warehouses,1,1,'')

PRINT @Warehouses

DECLARE @query varchar(2000)=CONCAT('SELECT Stockcode,',@Warehouses,'
FROM TestData PIVOT(MAX(Cost) FOR Warehouse IN(',@Warehouses,')) p')

PRINT @query

EXEC(@query)
```

My another answer similar to it - [Display count results of requests with results of jobs horizontally and locations vertically 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268049/display-count-results-of-requests-with-results-of-jobs-horizontally-and-location/47277892#47277892)

Comment: Thank you for the Dynamic query example. Never saw it like this so very helpful thank you.