# aggregate matrix elements row by row or column by column

Tags: sql-server

I have an application involving a 2D array like data structure which is saved into a table CellItem (one element one record)

```
CREATE TABLE CellItem ( 
    ID INT, 
    IdRow INT -- FK RowName, 
    IdCol INT -- FK ColName, 
    Value varchar(max))
```

In order to list row and column elements I defined 2 other tables RowItem and ColItem

```
CREATE TABLE RowItem ( ID INT, IdRow INT, IDCellIem INT)
CREATE TABLE ColItem ( ID INT, IdCol INT, IDCellIem INT)
```

where IDCellIem  is a foreign key refering ID in CellItem  table
and IdRow and IdCol are foreign key refering ID respectivelly in RowName and ColName defined below

```
CREATE TABLE RowName ( ID INT, name varchar(max))
CREATE TABLE ColName ( ID INT, name varchar(max))
```

I cannot come up with a concise solution. I am close to complete something which combines pivoting, dynamic SQL and STUFF statement nested into a cursor loop.
But I found it hell complicated.

Say for a 3x2 array I expect some kind of SELECT to return 3 record sets with 2 columns for row element or 2 record sets with 3 columns to list col elements
e.g.

I want to be able to list by columns with the result (not only one element by record set)

```
col name1 ; elt1,1 ; elt2,1
col name2 ; elt1,2 ; elt2,2
col name3 ; elt1,3 ; elt2,3
```

or by rows with the result (not only one element by record set)

```
row name1  ; elt1,1 ; elt1,2 ; elt1,3
row name2  ; elt2,1 ; elt2,2 ; elt2,3
```

my question is how to script a stored procedure to list the whole row or column elements that would fit into record sets as described above. It is easy to get a single row or col but more complicated to get all of them.
Formatting the ouput is performance critical for the client where I have 1000 rows x 200 columns

The close to compelte query is something like this similar to what @Leran2002 provided (following), where @VariableColumns is the list of column I want to select obtaine with a STUFF() statement (as I said my code is too complicated). #Temp table has the content from which I can pull the values

```
SET @Query = 
'
SELECT
    ' + @VariableColumns + '
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        [rowID] AS pivotVariable, 
        [value]
    FROM #Temp                  
) tmp
PIVOT 
(
    max([value])
    FOR pivotVariable in (' +  @VariableColumns + ')
) piv'

EXEC(@Query);
```

Comment: please provide the "I am close to complete" query

Comment: and sample data for each table would help too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cells can contains several values and you want to concatenate these values using comma you can try the following. See my comments. You can run all the script because I used temp tables for this example.

```
-- test tables and values
CREATE TABLE #CellItem(
  ID INT,
  IdRow INT, -- FK to RowName
  IdCol INT, -- FK to ColName
  Value varchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE #RowName ( ID INT, name varchar(max))
CREATE TABLE #ColName ( ID INT, name varchar(max))

INSERT #RowName(ID,name)VALUES
(1,'r1'),
(2,'r2'),
(9,'r9')

INSERT #ColName(ID,name)VALUES
(1,'c1'),
(2,'c2'),
(3,'c3'),
(9,'c9')

INSERT #CellItem(ID,IdRow,IdCol,Value)VALUES
(1,1,1,'v11-a'), (2,1,1,'v11-b'), -- cell(1,1) contains 2 values
(3,1,2,'v12-a'),
(4,1,3,'v13-a'),
(5,2,1,'v21-a'), (6,2,1,'v21-b'), (7,2,1,'v21-с') -- cell(2,1) contains 3 values

-- variant 1 - rows by vertical
DECLARE
  @colIndexes varchar(MAX)='',
  @colNames varchar(MAX)=''

SELECT
  @colIndexes+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID)),
  @colNames+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID),' ',QUOTENAME(name))
FROM ColName
--WHERE ID IN(SELECT DISTINCT IdCol FROM #CellItem) -- if you want to hide empty columns

SET @colIndexes=STUFF(@colIndexes,1,1,'')

PRINT @colIndexes
PRINT @colNames

DECLARE @query1 varchar(MAX)='SELECT n.ID IdRow,n.name NameRow'+@colNames+'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      k.IdRow,
      k.IdCol,
      STUFF(
          (
          SELECT ''; ''+i.Value
          FROM #CellItem i
          WHERE i.IdCol=k.IdCol AND i.IdRow=k.IdRow
          ORDER BY i.ID
          FOR XML PATH('''')
          ),1,2,'''') Value
    FROM
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT IdRow,IdCol
        FROM #CellItem
      ) k
  ) q PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR IdCol IN('+@colIndexes+')) p
JOIN #RowName n ON n.ID=p.IdRow -- use RIGHT JOIN if you want show empty rows
'

PRINT @query1
EXEC(@query1)

-- variant 2 - rows by horisontal
DECLARE
  @rowIndexes varchar(MAX)='',
  @rowNames varchar(MAX)=''

SELECT
  @rowIndexes+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID)),
  @rowNames+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID),' ',QUOTENAME(name))
FROM RowName
--WHERE ID IN(SELECT DISTINCT IdCol FROM #CellItem) -- if you want to hide empty rows

SET @rowIndexes=STUFF(@rowIndexes,1,1,'')

PRINT @rowIndexes
PRINT @rowNames

DECLARE @query2 varchar(MAX)='SELECT n.ID IdCol,n.name NameCol'+@rowNames+'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      k.IdRow,
      k.IdCol,
      STUFF(
          (
          SELECT ''; ''+i.Value
          FROM #CellItem i
          WHERE i.IdCol=k.IdCol AND i.IdRow=k.IdRow
          ORDER BY i.ID
          FOR XML PATH('''')
          ),1,2,'''') Value
    FROM
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT IdRow,IdCol
        FROM #CellItem
      ) k
  ) q PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR IdRow IN('+@rowIndexes+')) p
JOIN #ColName n ON n.ID=p.IdCol -- use RIGHT JOIN if you want show empty columns
'

PRINT @query2
EXEC(@query2)

DROP TABLE #CellItem
DROP TABLE #RowName
DROP TABLE #ColName
GO
```

You can use an additional temp table (see `#TempData`) instead the subquery

```
-- test tables and values
CREATE TABLE #CellItem(
  ID INT,
  IdRow INT, -- FK to RowName
  IdCol INT, -- FK to ColName
  Value varchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE #RowName ( ID INT, name varchar(max))
CREATE TABLE #ColName ( ID INT, name varchar(max))

INSERT #RowName(ID,name)VALUES
(1,'r1'),
(2,'r2'),
(9,'r9')

INSERT #ColName(ID,name)VALUES
(1,'c1'),
(2,'c2'),
(3,'c3'),
(9,'c9')

INSERT #CellItem(ID,IdRow,IdCol,Value)VALUES
(1,1,1,'v11-a'), (2,1,1,'v11-b'), -- cell(1,1) contains 2 values
(3,1,2,'v12-a'),
(4,1,3,'v13-a'),
(5,2,1,'v21-a'), (6,2,1,'v21-b'), (7,2,1,'v21-с') -- cell(2,1) contains 3 values


-- an additional temp table
SELECT
  k.IdRow,
  k.IdCol,
  STUFF(
      (
      SELECT '; '+i.Value
      FROM #CellItem i
      WHERE i.IdCol=k.IdCol AND i.IdRow=k.IdRow
      ORDER BY i.ID
      FOR XML PATH('')
      ),1,2,'') Value
INTO #TempData
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT IdRow,IdCol
    FROM #CellItem
  ) k



-- variant 1 - rows by vertical
DECLARE
  @colIndexes varchar(MAX)='',
  @colNames varchar(MAX)=''

SELECT
  @colIndexes+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID)),
  @colNames+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID),' ',QUOTENAME(name))
FROM ColName
--WHERE ID IN(SELECT DISTINCT IdCol FROM #CellItem) -- if you want to hide empty columns

SET @colIndexes=STUFF(@colIndexes,1,1,'')

PRINT @colIndexes
PRINT @colNames

DECLARE @query1 varchar(MAX)='SELECT n.ID IdRow,n.name NameRow'+@colNames+'
FROM #TempData q PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR IdCol IN('+@colIndexes+')) p
JOIN #RowName n ON n.ID=p.IdRow -- use RIGHT JOIN if you want show empty rows
'

PRINT @query1
EXEC(@query1)

-- variant 2 - rows by horisontal
DECLARE
  @rowIndexes varchar(MAX)='',
  @rowNames varchar(MAX)=''

SELECT
  @rowIndexes+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID)),
  @rowNames+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID),' ',QUOTENAME(name))
FROM RowName
--WHERE ID IN(SELECT DISTINCT IdCol FROM #CellItem) -- if you want to hide empty rows

SET @rowIndexes=STUFF(@rowIndexes,1,1,'')

PRINT @rowIndexes
PRINT @rowNames

DECLARE @query2 varchar(MAX)='SELECT n.ID IdCol,n.name NameCol'+@rowNames+'
FROM #TempData q PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR IdRow IN('+@rowIndexes+')) p
JOIN #ColName n ON n.ID=p.IdCol -- use RIGHT JOIN if you want show empty columns
'

PRINT @query2
EXEC(@query2)

DROP TABLE #TempData

DROP TABLE #CellItem
DROP TABLE #RowName
DROP TABLE #ColName
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question often ask here. For example - [Display count results of requests with results of jobs horizontally and locations vertically 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268049/display-count-results-of-requests-with-results-of-jobs-horizontally-and-location/47277892#47277892)

But I made scripts for your case, too. Hope I understood the question rightly. If I'm wrong please comment. And it'll be good if you give us some test data.

And I want to ask a question.
Why do you not use the following structure of `CellItem` without `RowItem` and `ColItem`?

```
CREATE TABLE CellItem(
  ID INT,
  IdRow INT, -- FK to RowName
  IdCol INT, -- FK to ColName
  Value varchar(max)
)
```

**My answer.**

Test data

```
CREATE TABLE CellItem ( ID INT, Value varchar(max))

CREATE TABLE RowItem ( ID INT, IdRow INT, IDCellIem INT)
CREATE TABLE ColItem ( ID INT, IdCol INT, IDCellIem INT)

CREATE TABLE RowName ( ID INT, name varchar(max))
CREATE TABLE ColName ( ID INT, name varchar(max))


INSERT RowName(ID,name)VALUES
(1,'r1'),
(2,'r2'),
(9,'r9')

INSERT ColName(ID,name)VALUES
(1,'c1'),
(2,'c2'),
(3,'c3'),
(9,'c9')

INSERT CellItem(ID,value)VALUES
(11,'v11'),
(12,'v12'),
(22,'v22'),
(23,'v23')

INSERT RowItem(ID,IdRow,IDCellIem)VALUES
(1,1,11),
(2,1,12),
(3,2,22),
(4,2,23)

INSERT ColItem(ID,IdCol,IDCellIem)VALUES
(1,1,11),
(2,2,12),
(3,2,22),
(4,3,23)
```

If you want show only filled rows and columns

```
DECLARE
  @colIndexes varchar(MAX)='',
  @colNames varchar(MAX)=''

SELECT
  @colIndexes+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID)),
  @colNames+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID),' ',QUOTENAME(name))
FROM ColName
WHERE ID IN(SELECT IdCol FROM ColItem) -- only filled columns

SET @colIndexes=STUFF(@colIndexes,1,1,'')

PRINT @colIndexes
PRINT @colNames

DECLARE @query varchar(MAX)='SELECT IdRow,NameRow'+@colNames+'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      r.IdRow,rn.name NameRow,
      c.IdCol,
      i.Value
    FROM CellItem i
    JOIN ColItem c ON i.ID=c.IDCellIem
    JOIN RowItem r ON i.ID=r.IDCellIem JOIN RowName rn ON rn.ID=r.IdRow
  ) q PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR IdCol IN('+@colIndexes+')) p
'

PRINT @query

EXEC(@query)
GO
```

Columns as rows

```
DECLARE
  @rowIndexes varchar(MAX)='',
  @rowNames varchar(MAX)=''

SELECT
  @rowIndexes+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID)),
  @rowNames+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID),' ',QUOTENAME(name))
FROM RowName
WHERE ID IN(SELECT IdRow FROM RowItem) -- only filled rows

SET @rowIndexes=STUFF(@rowIndexes,1,1,'')

PRINT @rowIndexes
PRINT @rowNames

DECLARE @query varchar(MAX)='SELECT IdCol,NameCol'+@rowNames+'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      r.IdRow,
      c.IdCol,cn.name NameCol,
      i.Value
    FROM CellItem i
    JOIN RowItem r ON i.ID=r.IDCellIem
    JOIN ColItem c ON i.ID=c.IDCellIem JOIN ColName cn ON cn.ID=c.IdCol
  ) q PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR IdRow IN('+@rowIndexes+')) p
'

PRINT @query

EXEC(@query)
GO
```

If you want to show all rows and columns

```
DECLARE
  @colIndexes varchar(MAX)='',
  @colNames varchar(MAX)=''

SELECT
  @colIndexes+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID)),
  @colNames+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID),' ',QUOTENAME(name))
FROM ColName

SET @colIndexes=STUFF(@colIndexes,1,1,'')

PRINT @colIndexes
PRINT @colNames

DECLARE @query varchar(MAX)='SELECT n.ID IdRow,n.name NameRow'+@colNames+'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      r.IdRow,
      c.IdCol,
      i.Value
    FROM CellItem i
    JOIN ColItem c ON i.ID=c.IDCellIem
    JOIN RowItem r ON i.ID=r.IDCellIem
  ) q PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR IdCol IN('+@colIndexes+')) p
RIGHT JOIN RowName n ON n.ID=p.IdRow
'

PRINT @query

EXEC(@query)
GO
```

Columns as rows

```
DECLARE
  @rowIndexes varchar(MAX)='',
  @rowNames varchar(MAX)=''

SELECT
  @rowIndexes+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID)),
  @rowNames+=CONCAT(',',QUOTENAME(ID),' ',QUOTENAME(name))
FROM RowName

SET @rowIndexes=STUFF(@rowIndexes,1,1,'')

PRINT @rowIndexes
PRINT @rowNames

DECLARE @query varchar(MAX)='SELECT n.ID IdCol,n.name NameCol'+@rowNames+'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      r.IdRow,
      c.IdCol,
      i.Value
    FROM CellItem i
    JOIN RowItem r ON i.ID=r.IDCellIem
    JOIN ColItem c ON i.ID=c.IDCellIem
  ) q PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR IdRow IN('+@rowIndexes+')) p
RIGHT JOIN ColName n ON n.ID=p.IdCol
'

PRINT @query

EXEC(@query)
GO
```

Comment: wow. I think you got it. Considering the long an complete answer you gave I'll go over the details and confirm if that what I wanted. Concerning the structure for CellItem I did it the way you did. sorry I wrote my post with (bad) memory

Comment: Do you want to use an additional expression with STUFF for Value? If it so then I think you can replace everywere 'i.Value' to 'STUFF(i.Value,...) Value'. 'i.Value' containts in internal subqery.

Comment: I added one more answer. A new variant does concatenation for several values for each cells. Hope it what you wanted. ) In your question I didn't understand what you mean by `STUFF`. Concatenation here does with `FOR XML PATH` statement. And after that the function `STUFF` only deletes first comma.